# Cloudinary Axios Transformation

Tags: javascript, axios, cloudinary

I want to transform a mp4 video using h.265 video codec when I upload it, but I dont know how.

I am using Axios to connect to cloudinary and this is my code (it works but I dont know how to implemente the codec).

```js
  //upload video
  var formData2 = new FormData();
  formData2.append('file', fileVideo);
   
  formData2.append('upload_preset', CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESETS);



  //formData2.append('format','png');
  axios({
    url: CLOUDINARY_URL,
    method: 'POST',

    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

    },
    data: formData2

  }).then(function(res){
    console.log("video");
  console.log(res.data);

  //https://res.cloudinary.com/marvinq/video/upload/vc_h265/baea9vumoxllkwjx51uy.mp4"
VIDEO_LINK = "https://res.cloudinary.com/jamesbond/video/upload/"+res.data.public_id+".mp4";
    
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the transformation directly into the Cloudinary URL. For example, this is setting the video codec to h264, the profile to baseline and the level to 3.1 https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/video/upload/vc_h264:baseline:3.1/dog.mp4

Comment: Yes. I know it. But that will consume my transformation plan for every download. So I prefer transform it, one time, when I upload it.